# Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу по Python

Tags: python

Реализуйте генератор, возвращающий бесконечную последовательность чисел из треугольника Паскаля.
Последовательность, возвращаемая генератором, должна выглядеть так: 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 3 1 1 4 6 4 1 1 5 10 10 5 1 1 6 15 20 15 6 1 1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1 1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1 1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1 ....
Генератор должен быть экономным по памяти, т.е. не хранить в себе все предыдущие вычисленные значения.

С самим треугольником у меня проблемы нет, но как превратить этот код в генератор я не понимаю.

```
n = int(input())
P = []

for i in range(n):
    row = [1]*(i + 1)
    for j in range(i + 1):
        if j != 0 and j != i:
            row[j] = P[i-1][j-1] + P[i-1][j]
    P.append(row)
for r in P:
    print(*r, end = ' ')
```

Comment: Приложите пожалуйста ваши попытки решения задачи. Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: посмотрите [тут](https://oeis.org/A007318), там даже есть реализация на python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На основе реализации из [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A007318)

```
import itertools

n = int(input())
P = []

def gen(p=None):
    it = itertools.count() if p is None else range(p, p+1)
    for row in it:
        x = 1
        yield x
        for m in range(row):
            x = (x * (row - m)) / (m + 1)
            yield x

def pt_ist(n):
    return list(itertools.islice(gen(), n))

#вывод
P = pt_ist(n)
print(*[round(x) for x in P], sep = ' ')
```

ввод:

> 55

вывод:

> 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 3 1 1 4 6 4 1 1 5 10 10 5 1 1 6 15 20 15 6 1
> 1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1 1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1 1 9 36 84 126 126
> 84 36 9 1

Comment: За наводку в ответ спасибо @Danis

Comment: Спасибо большое!